# Emulate audio from a gameboy ROM in javascript

Tags: javascript, emulation, 2d-games, gameboy

With this emulator http://www.codebase.es/jsgb/ I did this project https://github.com/rafaelcastrocouto/gbonline.

Now I want to emulate the sounds and music with the html5 audio API, but I have no idea where to start. I've looked at the emulator code and the manual but I'm far from understanding what's going on there.

Emulator code: https://github.com/rafaelcastrocouto/gbonline/blob/gh-pages/script.js
Manual: http://nocash.emubase.de/pandocs.htm

Can you guys explain me how it should be done, maybe some pseudo code???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that there are four ways to get sound out of emulator described in the Pan Docs referenced to in credits section [Codebase](http://www.codebase.es/jsgb/). Inside the Pan Docs section of I/O Ports is a chapter named [Sound Controller](http://nocash.emubase.de/pandocs.htm#soundcontroller). There is written:

> There are two sound channels connected to the output terminals SO1 and SO2. There is also a input terminal Vin connected to the cartridge. It can be routed to either of both output terminals. GameBoy circuitry allows producing sound in four different ways:
>
> - Quadrangular wave patterns with sweep and envelope functions.
> - Quadrangular wave patterns with envelope functions.
> - Voluntary wave patterns from wave RAM.
> - White noise with an envelope function.

So it's necessary to implement audio workers that match the characteristic of the previous list. For example using a library like [Flocking](https://github.com/colinbdclark/flocking), and build for each way sound can be created one synthesis matching the details in the following sections of that article.

After finishing that step an extension of `script.js` in your Git repo is necessary (like the other registers starting at [line 240](https://github.com/rafaelcastrocouto/gbonline/blob/9194d61ab304c3a76085ba7c2572171efab5a9c9/script.js#L240)) to connect [sound registers](http://nocash.emubase.de/pandocs.htm#soundcontrolregisters). Those registers need to trigger and select the appropriate synthesizer.

Hope this will help a bit.

Comment: Flocking seens like a good lib .. going to try it ... still dreaming about that git pull

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto what do you mean with that git pull allready pulled yours for research